# How can I do push button animations (using ImageVew)?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse, java, android aps.

How can I do a push effect on the `ImageView`? I'm using `GridView` and `setOnItemClick`.
I'm gonna to do something like this:

```
iv1.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_push);
//here i want to use any SLEEP function or something (but I dont want freeze app effect)
iv1.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_normal);
```

Do you know how can I do that, or maybe you have better ideas? (It should be simple). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documents of [Input Events](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html)

> onTouch() From View.OnTouchListener. This is called when the user performs an action qualified as a touch event, including a press, a release, or any movement gesture on the screen (within the bounds of the item).

So you can use a `onTouchListener` :

```
iv1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {        
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch(event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // PRESSED
            iv1.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_push);
            return true; // if you want to handle the touch event
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            // RELEASED
            iv1.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_normal);
            return true; // if you want to handle the touch event
    }
    return false;
}
});
```

**Here's a better way**

Instead of using `OnTouchListener` you can use drawable selector to change button's show state.

Create a selector xml file in `res/drawable`, for example "button_bg.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true"
  android:drawable="@drawable/button_push" /> <!-- pressed -->
<item android:state_focused="true"
   android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" /> <!-- focused -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Now inside your activity(may be inside `onCreate()`), you can just use

```
iv1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_bg);
```

And you can do whatever you want inside `iv1.setOnClickListener()` to handle click events.You don't have to bother now about setting your background resource in your code.It will automatically change accordingly when your button is pressed or focused.

Comment: but if im using GridView for dynamic ImageViews then what? OnTouchListener is possible for GridView? or i must use OnItemClick listener?

Comment: Please see my edits.Using the 2nd solution should solve your problem in an efficient way.

Comment: thank you but im trying and trying and does not work for me :(, Probabli im doing something wrong or that method didnt work with GridView? When i press the ImageView on GridView then no effect. I tried to set android:background="blabla in one XML file and no effect too

Comment: ahhh, i know, i had collision with setBackgroudResource :D, i deleted that BackgriundResource and now it works fine! Thanks bro :D

Comment: Glad it worked for you.Please accept this as the correct answer so that others can be beneficial from it.If it helped you then please consider upvoting too.

Comment: i know. And thanks again bro, you r awesome. I see, you r from India, i love you country :D

Comment: You're welcome. Happy to help you again if you post some new questions. :) Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
iv1.post(new Runnable{
    public void run(){
       iv1.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_push);
       //here i want to use any SLEEP function or something (but I dont want freeze app effect)
    }
});
```